# Adding a jekyll blog to myapp.com/blog to heroku

Tags: heroku, blogs, jekyll

Is there anything like the Bloggy gem that engine yard has?

"Let’s start with a simple concept. For SEO purposes it is better if your blog runs at http://mydomain.com/blog rather than http://blog.mydomain.com. We can go into detail here later but that’s really for an entirely different post. Again there are numerous ways of accomplishing this task but I want to talk about doing it with Jekyll."

http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2012/introducing-bloggy-a-simple-way-to-add-a-jekyll-blog-to-any-rails-application/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

are you asking if you can use bloggy too? if so then the answer is yes, I am the author of the bloggy gem (as well as that blog post) and you can use the bloggy gem simply by adding gem 'bloggy' to your gemfile

-Best
Zach

Comment: I just made an article on that cool bloggy: http://gitwatcher.com/blog/tumblr-to-jekyll-blog-migration.html